# removing all geometry from SceneKit, or modifying it on the fly

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a simple SceneKit view that displays antenna designs, like a TV antenna, or this less common example, a biquad.

[image]

These designs consist of a number of `SKCylinders` that are rotated and positioned.

Connected with that view is a NSTableView that lists the endpoints of the cylinders and lets the user edit them. When they exit an editor, the 3D view updates.

The problem is that my code current always *adds* new `SKCylinders` to the view with every redraw. So as they make edits, multiple copies of the `SKCylinders` end up in the view. I'm looking at the docs trying to figure out the best way to fix this.

1) should I simply remove all the geometry nodes before every draw and then make it fresh? Is there an easy way to find all the nodes that are geometry, rather than cameras or lights (or whatever)?

2) is there some way I can identify nodes within the collection so I could say that since line 5 of the geometry changed, I need to adjust node-with-something=5? I though about using `name` but I don't see a way to find a node by name

3) (2) is not a complete solution because I allow inserts and deletes in the list, so it might be "everything after this changes". Does that bring me to (1) or is there a better solution here?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used SceneKit yet but, from the documentation, it would seem that you can find nodes by name by calling:

```
SCNScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName( name, recursively: true)
```

or just iterate through childNodes recursively yourself.

Depending on the complexity of the nodes hierarchy, it may be tricky to implement insertions and deletions but, once you found the nodes you're looking for, that's just plumbing (prune and graft tree manipulations and such).

Comment: I ended up using this solution, and NSURLID as the name so I knew they were unique.